# Sending Message to user/group of users with uwsgi websockets

Tags: python, django, websocket, uwsgi

Recently I've been doing a lot of testing around different ways of serving our Django application. I've settled on uwsgi as it seems to fit our needs pretty well.

I've recently discovered that uwsgi also supports WebSockets and started looking into it and found some examples: https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/blob/master/tests/

After running the example (websockets_chat.py) and taking a look through uwsgi's documention for their websockets implementation it appears as though you can only send broadcast, or global messages.

Has anyone managed to find a way to transmit a message to a particular user or does uwsgi not support that level of communication yet?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing like broadcast or global messages in websockets specs. They only "upgrades" an http connection to a lower-level one. What you do with that connection is up to you. The examples show integration with redis as message exchanger but you are free to make other uses.

For your specific case you will need to build a shared list of connected users and implements routing. Remember, you cannot rely on node.js way as it is based on a single threaded setup so everything is way simpler. In uWSGI a websocket connection can happens on a thread, a process or a coroutine, so exchanging data between them is the key.